# How to simulate multiple iOS clients connecting to a server?

Tags: ios, testing, server

I am creating a service and an iOS  client app that will connect to the service. I am trying to make the client app modular, loosely coupled in its structure.

At some moment I will want to see how multiple clients connect to a service at one moment and how everything is performing.

What are the tools/approach to handle this task? Should I create a CLI utility app for Mac OS that inherits from iOS client app classes?

Should I create the iOS app the way that it has interfaces to its code to be consumed as something like API so that to interact with it from the CLI app?

Ideally, I would like to just run the part of the code that is in charge of business-logic, not UI stuff, so just seeing app logs in console is fine, not having to see 10 similar windows of the same working iOS app.

What are the solutions big boys use?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple tools I use for load testing web services:

[Apache Bench](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ApacheBench) (open source)

[loader.io](http://loader.io) (SaaS)

Another option is [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org), which I haven't tried, but seems powerful—and open source.

Comment: Should I separate testing of the iOS app and server code?

If so, then I need to create mock connections for the iOS app and basically test only against them and make sure they conform to real server code connections rules?

Comment: Yes, it would be ideal for your service tests to only be testing the service, and your iOS app tests should only be testing the iOS app. On the service end you can create tests, which spawn web clients that hit your API, and on the iOS app you should be able to create a request factory to mock the service. With that said, load testing is something I typically perform in the cli, outside of my automated test suite. Also, I measure performance on the live apps/services using tools like new relic.